# Bicycles on Batumi-Tbilisi train

Tags: trains, bicycles, georgia-country

I remember, some years ago, you could just take your bicycle on the trains in Georgia. With a bit of haggling. But as they changed the wagons to modern Stadler, is this still possible? And how would I purchase tickets in advance.

Edit: I'll be traveling on the last weekend of May 2020.

Comment: Interesting. These trains can be configured to accommodate up to 12 bicycles but only if the operator elects to have the cabin configured that way. I can't be sure whether GR has done this or not; their web site can hardly be said to exist and short of actually getting on a train to look I'm not sure if you'll get an answer.